# Using vis.js library in angular js to implement additional features

Tags: angularjs, vis.js

I am working with `vis.js` library in `angularjs`. I have created a simple network which looks as follows

[image]

My html div for the network is as follows

```
<div id="mynetwork">
   <vis-network data="data" options="options"></vis-network> 
</div>
```

and my controller is as follows

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngVis']);

App.controller('visController', ['$scope','$http','$window','VisDataSet',function($scope,$http,$window,VisDataSet)
{
    $scope.currentNodes = [];
    $scope.currentEdges = [];
    $http.post('/getCurrentNetworkData').success(function(response) 
    {
        $scope.currentNodes = response.currentNodes;
        $scope.currentEdges = response.currentEdges;

        $scope.options = {
            edges:{
                 font: {
                    align: 'bottom'
                }    
            },
            interaction: {
                navigationButtons: true,
                keyboard: true
            }
        }
        $scope.data = {
            "nodes" : $scope.currentNodes,
            "edges" : $scope.currentEdges
        }

    });
}]);
```

Now I want to put neighbourhood highlight feature into my network. It is available in `vis.js` examples but I want to do the same thing using `angular js`. Can someone help me in doing that?

Here is a link for the neighbourhood highlight example provided in the `vis.js` examples

http://visjs.org/examples/network/exampleApplications/neighbourhoodHighlight.html